# How to package (where to install) a stand-alone software bundle

Tags: software-installation, directory-structure, packaging

Consider some application that is intended to be built in its destination directory and whose subdirectory structure does not respect Linux conventions.  Assume in particular that there is no `install` target in `Makefile`.  Where can such bundle be installed?

It seems that, according to [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml), the only appropriate place [is `/opt`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s13.html).  Is this correct?  Can a software bundle be simply dropped into `/opt`?

Answer (score 1):

Related: [Where should Steam install game data on linux, to be FHS-compliant?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209472/116972)

I also recommend `/opt`, many vendors release their software regarding dirs in `/opt` as the default installation destination - `/opt/google/chrome`, `/opt/Xilinx/Vivado`, etc.

Of course it would be nice if local administrators would have an option to change that path.